# Scala: restrict parameter values

Tags: scala

Is there a way to restrict the values of a parameter in a Scala function?  For example, if I have one paramater called flag and I only want the user to be able to submit the values 0 or 1 as valid values for that parameter.

I know I could write a simple if statement that checked the values and returned an error message of some sort if it isn't acceptable, but I thought there might be a more succinct way to do it, say when the parameter is named in the function declaration.

Comment: Just to add that alternatively to the _simple if statement_, one can use `require()`, like:
`require(flag == 0 || flag == 1, "Wrong flag value");`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I would typically approach this in Scala is to make a base trait with case objects:

```
sealed trait Color
case object Red extends Color
case object Green extends Color
case object Blue extends Color

//...
def myFn(arg:Color) = //...
```

Comment: Underscore wrote a good blog post on this topic - http://underscore.io/blog/posts/2015/06/02/everything-about-sealed.html.

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect and actually solves another problem I have.  @KevinMeredith, wish I could get you some points for the link!

Answer (score 4):

What you want is "dependent typing". This sort of call would be a compile error in a language with support for it. Unfortunately scala doesn't support it.

Two typical workarounds would be to use an ADT instead of the larger type, or a wrapper with a restricted method of construction.

```
object ZeroOrOne {
  def apply(i: Int): Option[ZeroOrOne] = if (i == 0 || i == 1) Some(ZeroOrOne(i)) else None
}
case class ZeroOrOne private (i: Int)
def doStuff(zo: ZeroOrOne) { // use zo.i }
```

or

```
sealed trait EnableStatus
case object Enabled extends EnableStatus
case object Disabled extends EnableStatus

def setEnabled(es: EnableStatus)
```